# Trouble installing php 7 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm trying to install PHP 7. I'm doing something wrong. I [followed these directions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-14-04-install-php7-using-apt-get-command/).

If I type 'php -v' in terminal it shows php 7.

However, if I look at my phpinfo() the output still shows my old php 5.

Now when I try to install something that requires php 7 I get the following error:

```
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

        Problem 1
          - Installation request for alchemy/zippy 0.3.5 -> satisfiable by 
alchemy/zippy[0.3.5].
          - alchemy/zippy 0.3.5 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP 
extension mbstring is missing from your system.
        Problem 2
          - Installation request for easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.1 -> satisfiable by 
easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.1].
          - easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested 
PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
        Problem 3
          - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 4.8.27 -> satisfiable by
 phpunit/phpunit[4.8.27].
          - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.27 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP 
extension dom is missing from your system.
        Problem 4
          - alchemy/zippy 0.3.5 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP 
extension mbstring is missing from your system.
          - drupal/console 0.11.3 requires alchemy/zippy 0.3.5 -> satisfiable
 by alchemy/zippy[0.3.5].
          - Installation request for drupal/console 0.11.3 -> satisfiable by 
drupal/console[0.11.3].

        To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini 
files:
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
          - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
        You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are
 used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Anyone have any idea what I need to fix to run php 7 on my system?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error output you have pasted says it all - you are missing `mbstring` and `dom` extensions.  Those can be installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-dom php7.0-mbstring
```

The packages with PHP extensions have correct `Provides:` field, so right packages will be chosen.

Comment: This answer helped me. My environment was Ubuntu 14.04 and php version was 5.5.9